# How to select a boundary edge and generate an outline

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I'm looking for two features in Geometry Node:

- Is there a way to select edges and convert them into a curve/solid outline
- Is there a way to specifically select edges that are on the border, as in they do not share a border with another triangle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's very simple in geonodes, just select edges that have only one neighbor (face):

[image]

Testing with a Suzanne with one half removed:

[image]