How to create border outline?
I tried many different ways to create a border outline for my objects. The outline helper add on, to duplicate the meshes and convert the border edges to grease pencil and I tried Geometry Nodes. But I am not able to receive the needed result.
I created a model of a globe. Each country has its own mesh.

In the solid viewport, it looks great with the borders. If I switch to the renderer viewport or export the model as an usdz, the borders disappear (of course).
How can I add such borders for each country in an useful way?
After finishing the project, I need to export it as an usdz file to add it to a Virtual Reality app. Unfortunately, I need to consider it when finding a solution for the borders.
Feel free to download the blend file to test some things:

I removed some countries in this blend file, because of the allowed file size in Blend Exchange.
I would really appreciate any help or ideas I get.

"I cannot upload the file for you, because of the file size..." - but what you can do, is prepare an example project, that has the same properties specific to your problem, but weighs less. How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice

@MarkusvonBroady You are right, I uploaded a file with less countries. Thanks

Related to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/313541/how-to-select-a-boundary-edge-and-generate-an-outline

If you add a cube to the scene, and add a Geometry Nodes setup to it:

Then you will get a curve defined by geometry, which should be exportable to any 3D format:


Thanks for your answer. Could you please upload your blend file, I do not understand it completely at the moment. I would like to check it out.

Okay, seems to work. I will check it in the application.

@PascalMeger do you have problems reproducing this setup? Take a screenshot of yours

No, it worked. Thanks :)
